# Javafx in Fedora

Tags: fedora

I knew that someone already asked this question, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126217/openjdk-does-not-work-with-javafx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk). But I cannot find the true answer. Can anyone explain me how to make javafx project in fedora?

My java version:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_65"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

And my netbean version:

> Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)

So now, I want to know how to fix it. My OS is Fedora 21, 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

For the JavaFX runtime:

```
dnf install javafx
```

(This actually ends up doing the same as `dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-javafx`).

For the SDK:

```
dnf install javafx-devel
```

(This actually ends up doing the same as `dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-javafx-devel`)

This was added to Fedora around June 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Just install Oracle JDK since the Fedora can't distribute closed source JavaFX within OpenJDK.

Edit: rumor is that OpenJDK9 will provide JavaFX too.

Answer (score 0):

Developers who works with IntelliJ. In the first step you have to install openjfx.

```
sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-openjfx-devel
```

After installation you can find the mandatory war files in

```
/usr/lib/jvm/openjfx/rt/lib/ext
```

Now you must add these libs to your Project!

```
Click on your Project-> Press F4 -> Click on Global Libraries -> Click on the + -> Choose Java and use the given path from above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 36 here. You'll need to install OpenJFX.

```bash
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 36 (Thirty Six)
```

```bash
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.6.0.10-1.fc36) (build 17.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-17.0.6.0.10-1.fc36) (build 17.0.6+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Just install openjfx

```bash
$ sudo dnf install -y OpenJFX
```

Then I can run JetUML like this:

```bash
java --module-path "/usr/lib/jvm/openjfx" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.swing,java.desktop,java.prefs -jar ~/JetUML-3.5.jar
```

Where */usr/lib/jvm/openjfx* is the location of the OpenJFX files.